# What are the differences of Near in the manga version?

Tags: death-note

In Death Note, I've read that Near displays more emotions and (more interestingly) shows greater insight and deduction ability than his anime counterpart.

What are the differences of Near from his anime counterpart? Is the above statement true? (And if so, please provide examples.)

*There is another question, [How different are the anime and manga versions of Death Note](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/665/how-different-are-the-anime-and-manga-versions-of-death-note), but that just takes into question the ending.*

Answer (score 3):

## Appearance

In the manga, Near is only ever seen wearing white pajamas, while in the anime, his pants are light blue.

In [L: Change the WorLd](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/L:_Change_the_WorLd_%28live_action_film%29), Near is a Thai boy and the sole survivor of a village ravaged by disease. In the live action film, he has black hair, while in the [novel](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/L:_Change_the_WorLd_%28novel%29) he is described as the original Near in the series (while I haven't read the novel I would assume this means he has white hair).

## Personality

Near shows much more emotion in the manga than he does in the anime, particularly his facial expressions. A quote from the wiki shows an example of this:

> When the SPK members were killed in the anime Near has a very stern look, but in the manga he is visibly upset.

His facial expressions were probably more towards his smiling when he got things right, which was used to foreshadow the end where he smiles after seeing Ryuk, confirming to himself that Light is Kira.

---

Source: [Death Note Wikia site](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Near)

Answer (score -1):

I know this answer comes late. But i still hope my answer can help you. Well in the manga he is as cold as in the anime. However, in the manga, Near is smarter than in the Anime.

Comment: Could you please clarify that a bit more?  What makes him seem smarter in the manga? I understand you cannot site a lack of him being warmer in the manga but a claim of brilliance could be flushed out.